# Retrive Image URL of Custom Fields in Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I Have Created Custom Fields for Custom Post Type. when I retrieve the Values in Theme template image value returning 22.
How can I get the image URL.?

```
<?php
    $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1, 
    'post_type'        => 'projects', 
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    );
    $projects = get_posts( $args );

    foreach ($projects as $project) { 
        echo $project->project_title; // Title Text
        echo $project->project_description; // Description Content
        echo $project->project_image; // 22

     } ?>
```

When i Print $project

```
WP_Post Object
(
    [ID] => 35
    [post_author] => 1
    [post_date] => 2017-04-07 05:50:29
    [post_date_gmt] => 2017-04-07 05:50:29
    [post_content] => Tekzenit
    [post_title] => Tekzenit
    [post_excerpt] => 
    [post_status] => publish
    [comment_status] => closed
    [ping_status] => closed
    [post_password] => 
    [post_name] => tekzenit
    [to_ping] => 
    [pinged] => 
    [post_modified] => 2017-04-07 06:12:54
    [post_modified_gmt] => 2017-04-07 06:12:54
    [post_content_filtered] => 
    [post_parent] => 0
    [guid] => http://10.180.82.8/fareed/?post_type=projects&p=35
    [menu_order] => 0
    [post_type] => projects
    [post_mime_type] => 
    [comment_count] => 0
    [filter] => raw
)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Did you create **Custom Meta Fields** (project_title,project_description,project_image) for you Custom Post Type? Also did you get the value of project_title and project_description?

Comment: Did you remember to set the ACF to return either the URL or the object? it might just be returning the ID if you haven't set it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$project->project_image` returns the id

You can user `wp_get_attachment_image_url` function to get the image URL

```
if($project->project_image){   
   $imagePath =  wp_get_attachment_image_url( $project->project_image, '' );                                                                       
   echo imagePath
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some more info would be helpful on how you created the custom fields like if you used advanced custom fields or wrote the code yourself.

But if you have the image ID then you can use:

```
$img_id = $project->project_image;
$img_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($img_id, 'full' );
$img_url = $img_array[0];
echo $img_url;
```